# How do I import an openstreetmaps shape file in R and extract lat/long centroids?

Tags: r, geospatial, latitude-longitude, shapefile, rgdal

I am trying to import an openstreetmaps shape file in R using the rgdal package.
The shape file I downloaded has 5 components in it:

```
places.cpg
places.dbf
places.prj
places.shp
places.shx
```

The files can be accessed at the following location:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ITb_7lHh1EUFVfVWc4ekRfSnc

I have to do the following:
1) Import the shape file
2) Extract lat/long of the point or centroid of shape in case of polygon
3) Attach the lat/long pair to the dbf file to do some analysis

I am stuck in the first stage of import itself, I am running the following code:

```
shape1 <- readOGR(dsn = "try", layer = "places")
```

Here 'try' is the folder in my working directory where all the 5 'places' file from openstreetmaps mentioned above are located.

I get the following error when doing this:

```
Error in readOGR(dsn = "try", layer = "places") : no features found
In addition: Warning message:
In ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv =
use_iconv,  : ogrInfo: all features NULL
```

I need help with this import. Alternatively if there is a way to directly extract lat/long from one of the places shape file, I can just open the places.dbf file in excel and add the lat/long.

Comment: it's be helpful if there were a link to the shapefile

Comment: I completely forgot about that..have added a link to access the shape files:'
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ITb_7lHh1EUFVfVWc4ekRfSnc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you are facing troubles with the readOGR() function**: Another possibility is to use the `maptools` package. It creates `SpatialXXXDataFrames` so you can use all the functions from `rgeos`etc.

```
library(maptools)

setwd("/your/data/path/")

places <- readShapeSpatial("places")
# ... your geospatial functions, like
plot(places)
```

probably you will have to adjust the projection of the spatial data. For OSM-Data you will need to find the `proj4string` for WGS84 (or EPSG:4326) at [spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org).

Thus you can adjust your projection in R:

```
proj4string(places) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
```

For the calculation/"extraction" of polygon centroids see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36673750/3250126) post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the shapefile (`.shp`) as the DSN. Turning the `SpatialPointsDataFrame` into a "normal" `data.frame` will give "ugh" column names
for lang & lat, so you can rename them to make them more usable:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

places <- readOGR("places/places.shp", "places", verbose=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

places_df <- setNames(as.data.frame(places),
                      c("osm_id", "name", "type", "population", "longitude", "latitude"))

head(places_df)

##     osm_id          name    type population longitude latitude
## 1 25431184   Stockertown village         NA -75.26156 40.75446
## 2 25716549 Mechanicsburg village         NA -77.00473 40.21020
## 3 25762119     Mansfield  hamlet         NA -77.07929 41.80569
## 4 25840249  New Columbia  hamlet         NA -76.87368 41.03368
## 5 25840585  Williamsport    town      29381 -77.00277 41.24933
## 6 25930002       Hershey    town      14257 -76.65060 40.28549
```

Comment: I changed the working directory to the folder where the places shape file is located and ran the following code

shape1 <- readOGR(dsn = "places.shp", "places", verbose=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

I am still getting the no features found error. Am I still doing something wrong?\

Comment: @Shaz - I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: I couldn't... I used maptools instead as suggested by the next post

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this package to work but the package "shapefiles" did the work for me. It has a read.shapefile function that imports shapefiles.