# Extract centroid of shape file object in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile, centroid

I have a shape file, uploaded at the following path:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ITb_7lHh1EUFVfVWc4ekRfSnc

I imported the data using the "read.shapefiles" function in "shapefiles" package:

```
landuse<- read.shapefile("landuse")
```

I now need to extract the lat/long centroids of all the shapes within the landuse object and add it to the landuse$dbf dataframe

I tried two things:

```
lu_df<-coordinates(landuse)
lu_df<-SpatialPoints(landuse)
```

Both gave me the following error:

```
Error in coordinates(as.data.frame(obj)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'coordinates': Error in data.frame(record = 1L, content.length = 80L, shape.type = 5L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 4, 7
```

I am not sure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I recommend using the `rgdal` package for spatial data. The `readOGR` and `writeOGR` functions provide nice Shapefile handling (like input and output of projections etc.).

**UPDATE**:
Since this is not working for @Shaz (see error in comments), the `maptools`function `readShapePoly()`was utilized. Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36674077/3250126).

To your problem: The `rgeos` package provides a function `gCentroid()` which calculates the centroid of your polygons. The solution looks something like this:

```
setwd("/path/to/your/shapefile/")

library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
landuse <- readShapePoly("landuse") 

centr <- gCentroid(landuse, byid = TRUE)

# create SpatialPointsDataFrame to export via writeOGR
# positive side effect: All data from landuse@data joined to centr@data
centr <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(centr, data= landuse@data) 

writeOGR(centr, ".", "landuse_centroids", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: I don't know why I am unable to use the readOGR function.. I always get the following error:

Error in readOGR(".", "landuse") : no features found
In addition: Warning message:
In ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
  ogrInfo: all features NULL

Comment: use `library(maptools)`. I changed the answer.

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot.. any idea why readOGR is not working for me?

Comment: Are you working on a Win or Linux machine? Perhaps problems with the GDAL installation. Have you tried updating R and the `rgdal` package?

Comment: I am working on windows machine... I am on R 0.99.489 and the latest rgdal package

Comment: R is currently on version 3.2.5, probably you mean R-Studio version 0.99... You can find out the the version of R by typing `sessionInfo()` into the console.

Comment: Ok.. I am on 3.2.2

Comment: have you tried updating R to the current version yet?

Comment: No...it's unfortunately installed on server... and I am not the admin on it.

Comment: Then I don't know a better answer than to use `library(maptools)` with `readShapeSpatial()`, sry

Comment: Thanks loki.. I used your recommendation and it worked. That's why I have marked the question as answered..